# Cannot generate token via Here Map API in php

Tags: php, here-api

I have successfully obtained my hERE MAP API signature.

Now Am working with Here Map API to generate token. [source link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication-authorization/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html) here is the request payload

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: account.api.here.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="1tqA_sample1fLhs2z6_q1l",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1512072698",oauth_nonce="ZGAaMP",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Q0sample4lqICrx19%2F4ahaH%2Fi2O0NgqDUQJgti5U3Q%3D"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 
grant_type=client_credentials
```

I have implemented the code below but it throws error  **mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong**

**here is the code**

```
$url2="https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL, $url2);



//$post_add = "grant_type=client_credentials";
$post_add=array('grant_type'=> 'client_credentials');
$access_key_id ="my keys goes here";
$timer = time();



curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Host: account.api.here.com",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key='$access_key_id',oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA256',oauth_timestamp='$timer',oauth_nonce='ccZGAaMP',oauth_version='1.0',oauth_signature='my signature goes here'",
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));  



curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');

//curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_add);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);

print_r($response2);
```

Comment: Where are you actually calculating the signature here? It looks like you are using a static value, that has nothing to do with your current, specific request?

Comment: I obtained signature from a different API Cal and l so the value there was just for sample

Comment: But https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication-authorization/dev_guide/topics/creating-signature.html#creating-signature says, _“You must create a new signature for each token request to the Authentication and Authorization API. Signatures can only be used once.”_

Comment: You need to convert generated oauth signature into base64 string while passing to request the tokens.https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python

Answer (score 0):

This issue was simply resolved. i need to generated the oauth signature and convert it to basee64 while passing the token as suggested in the comments section and
[documentation](https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python)