# PHP - Getting bearer token from HERE REST API throws a signature mismatch error

Tags: php, here-maps-rest

before posting this question I have searched a solution for a long but all the snippets of code I tried always failed. It sounds really weird that there aren't working examples available in PHP!

I want to use HERE Maps REST API to geocode mail addresses. I have created my account and got the credentials as prerequisite.

Reference articles I followed are:

- https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python
- [Cannot generate token via Here Map API in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65175557/cannot-generate-token-via-here-map-api-in-php)
- [HERE Maps: Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250792/here-maps-invalid-client-authorization-header-expecting-signed-request-format)
- https://developer.here.com/documentation/identity-access-management/dev_guide/topics/postman.html

The code I have developed is a combination/adaption of these referenced articles:

```
//This snippet is for signature
$timer = time();
$grant_type = 'client_credentials';
$oauth_consumer_key = 'here.access.key.id';
$oauth_nonce = (string)((int) ($timer * 1000));
$oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
$oauth_timestamp = (string) ((int) ($timer));
$oauth_version = '1.0';
$url = 'https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token';
$access_key_secret = "here.access.key.secret";

$parameter_string = 'grant_type='.$grant_type;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_consumer_key='.$oauth_consumer_key;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_nonce='.$oauth_nonce;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_signature_method='.$oauth_signature_method;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_version='.$oauth_version;
$encode_parameter_string = urlencode($parameter_string);

$encoded_base_string = 'POST'.'&'.urlencode($url).'&'.$encode_parameter_string;

$signing_key = $access_key_secret.'&';

$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $encoded_base_string, $signing_key, true);

$encodedSignature = base64_encode($signature);

//This snippet is for getting the bearer token
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'oauth_consumer_key: '.urlencode($oauth_consumer_key),
    'oauth_nonce: '.urlencode($oauth_nonce),
    'oauth_signature: '.urlencode($encodedSignature),
    'oauth_signature_method: '.urlencode($oauth_signature_method),
    'oauth_timestamp: '.urlencode($oauth_timestamp),
    'oauth_version: '.urlencode($oauth_version),
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization: OAuth  oauth_consumer_key="'.urlencode($oauth_consumer_key).'",oauth_signature_method="'.urlencode($oauth_signature_method).'",oauth_timestamp="'.urlencode($oauth_timestamp).'",oauth_nonce="'.urlencode($oauth_nonce).'",oauth_version="'.urlencode($oauth_version).'",oauth_signature="'.urlencode($encodedSignature).'"'
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

This seems to avoid the wrong formatting of the request, the main error message I used to get as response. Unfortunately, the new error thrown with this snippet is "errorCode":401300,"message":"Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong." but I am sure that the credentials I am passing are correct.

I suspect there is something wrong in the signature snippet. Any clue? Can you help me to provide a reference for HERE Oauth signature in PHP?
Thanks for sharing your comments!

Answer (score 0):

I made it!
I missed a parameter in the signature and the $encodedSignature must be further url-encoded. Then I was able to get my access token.
I am embedding the full working code, hoping that this may help the community:

```
<?php
$timer = (string) time();
$grant_type = 'client_credentials';
$oauth_consumer_key = 'my_consumer_key';
$oauth_nonce = uniqid(mt_rand(1, 1000));
$oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
$oauth_timestamp = $timer;
$oauth_version = '1.0';
$url = 'https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token';
$access_key_secret = "my_access_key_secret";

$parameter_string = 'grant_type='.$grant_type;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_consumer_key='.$oauth_consumer_key;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_nonce='.$oauth_nonce;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_signature_method='.$oauth_signature_method;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_timestamp='.$oauth_timestamp;
$parameter_string .= '&oauth_version='.$oauth_version;
$encoded_parameter_string = urlencode($parameter_string);

$encoded_base_string = 'POST'.'&'.urlencode($url).'&'.$encoded_parameter_string;

$signing_key = $access_key_secret.'&';

$signature = hash_hmac('SHA256', $encoded_base_string, $signing_key, true);

$encodedSignature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="'.$oauth_consumer_key.'",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="'.$oauth_timestamp.'",oauth_nonce="'.$oauth_nonce.'",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="'.$encodedSignature.'"',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

Comment: I did the same but still getting same error.

Comment: @GhanuBha I suppose you have created your account at HERE first, and then activated the Freemium REST API to get the access credentials. If this is the case, I can confirm this code is working fine for a week now. Have you edited your code? Please can you share it?

Comment: Thank for the answer. It works. My I have some issue that time. but now it is running.